# NetBeans commenting

Tags: netbeans, ide, comments, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using the popular IDE `NetBeans` and I have problems commenting code on the same line. For example, let's say we have the following line:

> `<h1> Some text </h1>` comment for h1

I would like to comment the part `"comment for h1"` through a key combination or some other means but without having to type  manually and without transferring the comment string to the next line. I usually use ctrl+/ but this key combination comments the whole line, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Why not Select & Replace all such occurences.

You can use `Ctrl + Shift + H` and enter the text which you want to replace.

Add the text (say **comment for h1**) to be commented in the field `Containing Text`, and replace that text with **//comment for h1** in the `Replace With` field.

[image]

Then it will show you all the matches which you want to comment. You can select the desired places where you want to place comment before the text.

Finally, click on **`Replace ? Matches`** button. Voila, that's it...

[image]

Comment: I don't want to do this, @shekhar suman. I can't believe you're proposing it.

Comment: @Sycamore-No, I thought if you're thinking of commenting out all the presence of your word. There is no harm in that case, it can come handy there... Never mind, it can help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can always create your own keyboard shortcut, see how in this [link](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2013/06/customising-your-keyboard-shortcuts-in-netbeans-ide/).

Then you can customize your keyboard to replace your highlighted text with the same text with `/* */` , `//` , `<!-- -->` or any others before/surrounding the text.

**Example:**

```
<h1> Some text </h1> comment for h1
```

Highlight the text you need to comment (comment for h1).

Use your customixed shortcut and:

```
<h1> Some text </h1> /*comment for h1*/
```

I haven't tested this, please tell me your feedback ;)

Comment: #SaintLike, I think that your idea only works with the existing NetBeans commands like ctrl+/ , but this command comments the entire line.
The closest I have come to what I want is to record a macro for the comment and then type the text in it.

Comment: Maybe, I haven't used netbeans in a while now so I'm not sure if it will work with customised shortcuts. Maybe a macro is just the way to go. Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to do this by recording 2 macros and assigning shortcuts to them:

1. ctrl + shift + A for the html comment `<!--  -->`
2. ctrl + shift + \ for the php comment `/*  */`.

Both macros position the mouse cursor in the middle of the comment section so it is convenient to enter a comment. This doesn't work with an existing comment.

Answer (score -1):

select the texe and use Ctrl+Shift+C

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+C will comment the entire line, including the code.

Comment: you can write <!-- comment for h1 --> on text you want to comment it